# Unity Facebook SDK - AppRequest

Tags: facebook, mobile, request, unity-game-engine

Just started implementing the Unity Facebook SDK into my latest project and I'm curious to see if anybody else is having problems with the following:

```
FB.AppRequest("Custom message");
```

This is as basic as I can make this function call yet when you receive the app request you just see:

"**GAME NAME: FRIEND NAME** sent you a **request**"

Am I missing something here? I've seen requests with custom messages from other games. Is it because I'm deploying to mobile and the 'message' parameter of a request doesnt work on mobile (like filter / exludeIDs is broken)?

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Have you called all the proper init and login methods, including waiting for their callbacks?

Comment: Sure have, my game is so dependant on FB it can't advance past the menu screen without being initialized and logged in via FB callbacks, and the ability to send app requests is well past that point.

Comment: I am having same kind of issue. After picking up the friend, callback function is being called. but on Facebook request of that person is not being shown. i am facing this on ios. i am using 5.0.4 facebook sdk for unity

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm not off-base here, but I'm working on the same type of requests. According to what I've been working with here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/

it covers implementing an action with an object into the request, which will result in a custom message. So for example, you could have a message like:
    GAMENAME: FRIENDNAME sent you a Life

Edit - I didn't have the signature of AppRequest as follows before, but after updating my SDK to version 5.1, it is now available:

According to the page, Unity implements it with:

```
public static void AppRequest(
string message,
OGActionType actionType,
string objectId,
string[] to,
string data = "",
string title = "",
FacebookDelegate callback = null)

// For 1:N requests
public static void AppRequest(
string message,
OGActionType actionType,
string objectId,
string filters = "",
string[] excludeIds = null,
int? maxRecipients = null,
string data = "",
string title = "",
FacebookDelegate callback = null)
```

I hope this provides a little direction and perhaps your solution. I'm working to implement this myself right now. Check out the link for more details :)